# Is there an easy way to pull the document tree from an html page using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, dom

I'm currently trying to compare between webpages (really, clustering them) for a "little" project for fun. I found a few papers on this (Gowda & Mattman 2016, among others) that led me into comparing the DOMs using tree edit distance. While I've found a few libraries that enable me to do so (https://pypi.org/project/zss/1.1.4/, https://pypi.org/project/apted/), I've had less success in finding solutions for pulling the dom. Most of what I've been able to find has been info about traversing the tree in lxml or bs4.

In my digging on SO, I found a library that does let you compare between html pages and uses the ZSS algorithm (https://pypi.org/project/vanguardkit/), but looking over their code, they are using bs4 as a backend and then looping through the soup object recursively to generate the document tree for each page to compare. It feels like there has to be an easier way to get at the document tree, but most of what I've seen in answers on SO seem to suggest there isn't.

This is a long winded way to ask, but is there an easy way to just pull the document tree from html (using Python)? I ask because what I really want, is the document tree (preferably in bracket notation) so I can pass it into the apted algorithm (or pass it in with some minor work). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, at first you have HTML document in string form. You have to parse this string (either with `lxml`, `html.parse`, `htm5lib`, `bs4` or some other means) and transform this output to string that apted understands. So I'm not aware of other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I ended up doing is making a class and a method and looping through the bs4 object. Kinda sad there wasn't a more elegant way to do so, but this might help someone in the future so I felt I should post it. I also am sharing what I did afterwards just in case that's helpful to anyone, but, again, I'm disappointed with the lack of elegance this code shows.

```
# we're only importing bs4 for the type hint tbh, but it matters to me
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class dom_tree:
    """
    a class to hold the dom tree from the webpage
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        this is the default instantiation parameters for this class
        """
        self.tree = "" # a blank string to hold the bracket notation tree structure    
    
    def bs4_to_tree(self: str, tag: bs4.element.Tag):
        """
        method to pull the tree of a bs4 object and return it in bracket notation    

        parameters
        ------------
        self.tree: str
            the attribute which contains the tree structure of the dom tree in bracket notation

        tag: bs4.element.Tag
            the bs4 element tag

        returns
        ------------
        self.tree: str
            the attribute which contains the tree structure of the dom tree in bracket notation
        """
        if tag.children:
            for child in tag.findChildren(recursive=False): # recursive = False b/c otherwise, it messes things up
                if child.findChildren: # if there are kids, add the child name which has kids, then add the tree to it
                    self.tree += "{" + child.name
                    self.tree = self.bs4_to_tree(child)
                    self.tree += "}"

                else: # if no kids, then it's just the tag inside brackets
                    self.tree += "{" + child.name + "}"

        else: # if no kids, then it's just the tag inside brackets
            self.tree += "{" + child.name + "}"

        return self.tree
```

Since I was working with pandas to hold the html I'd already scraped, I just kept going with that.

```
import pandas as pd
emb_df = pd.read_csv("emb_htmls_cleaned.csv") # reading my csv in which has the html

emb_df["bs4_obj"] = emb_df["url_html"].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x)) # creating bs4 objects from the html w/lambda func

emb_df["dom_trees"] = dom_tree() # making a column of dom trees to fill in

dom_trees = emb_df["dom_trees"] # making a list of the dom trees
bs4_objs = emb_df["bs4_obj"] # making another list of the objects

# applying my method to the bs4 objects; had to use a lambda and operate on the row level for all cols sadly -> inelegant solution
emb_df["dom_trees"] = emb_df.apply(lambda x: x["dom_trees"].bs4_to_tree(x["bs4_obj"]), axis=1)

emb_df = emb_df.drop(columns=["bs4_obj"])
```